# How to secure a blockchain based on PoW against 51% attack?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

I couldn't find a satisfying answer to this 51% attack issue, so for a new blockchain with only 300 mined blocks, from my understanding the attacker has to rebuild all the blocks from scratch, is that true, if yes then what if the blockchain has 100k or 300k blocks? is there a way to prevent or penalize a miner if he mines too fast? does having honest miners would solve the issue? what about multiple Full nodesI need practical solutions

Comment: Maybe running a mining pool by higher power than attacker poser solve your problem

Comment: I'm actually mining using cpu and I don't have any GPU, even renting is quite expensive, how about a higher coinbase maturity and higher required confirmation number up to 50 ?

Comment: Maturity not solve your problem

Comment: then what to adjust that would help in your opinion

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic checkpoints, as same as it used in Peercoin or Emercoin.